# Proving $\int_{C_0}f(z-z_0)dz=\int_Cf(z)dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I am working on a homework problem for my analysis class. I was given this. Suppose that $C_0$ and $C$ are two circles, $z=z_0+Re^{i\theta} \text{ for } (-\pi\le\theta\le\pi)$ and $z=Re^{i\theta} \text{ for } (-\pi\le\theta\le\pi)$. I need to show that $$\int_{C_0}f(z-z_0)dz=\int_Cf(z)dz$$

Assume that $f$ is continuous and piecewise on $C$.

Comment: What are you allowed to know? What work have you done so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: More for when asking homework questions, it is better to show where you are having problems.

Comment: Ok I will keep it in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since,
$$\int_{C_0}{f(z-z_0)}\,dz=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{f\left(Re^{i\theta}\right)Rie^{i\theta}}\,d\theta$$
$$\int_{C}{f(z)}\,dz=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{f\left(Re^{i\theta}\right)Rie^{i\theta}}\,d\theta$$
Therefore,
$$\int_{C_0}{f(z-z_0)}\,dz=\int_{C}{f(z)}\,dz$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $T : \Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{C}$ be given by $T(z) = z-z_0$. We notice that $DT = \operatorname{Id}$ and $T(C_0) = C$. Hence, 
$$\int_{C_0} f(z-z_0) \, dz = \int_{C_0} f(T(z)) \,dz = \int_{T(C_0)} f(z)\, |\det(DT)|\,dz = \int_C f(z)\,dz$$